# vote for users on drupal7

Tags: 7

I need the functionality to be able to have a vote widget on a profile page.  So users can be voted for and the user with the most votes wins.

(the users profile page is done with panels & views)

Ive played around with the flag module and it somewhat works for what I want, also the vote module, but it seems to only work on nodes and comments and doesnt work on user pages...

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: what doesn't flag do that you need done?

Comment: It's ok for now...but down the road I may have different views that load users and how many votes they have with the ability to vote still.  I am just not sure if this is possible since the flag is attached the profile node and not the actual user.

Comment: well the node->uid is the same as the user->uid so you have that connection.  if you are concerned with flagging the specific user, you can create a user flag and put that on the profile page yourself pretty easily as well, eg, load the profile's uid and then "feed" that to the user flag.

Comment: I suppose you are right @Jimajamma, I will give this a go for now.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to add fivestars module to your website, but then your users will be voted with stars instead of flags.

If you dont mind that you have to:

1. install [fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar) module
2. add a field on your user profile of type "Fivestar Rating"
3. add a rule so people cant vote on themselves using [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.

hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for me, I need an actual number count.

Comment: How about the RATE module? https://drupal.org/project/rate

Comment: I tried the rate module, but couldn't get it to work on a profile page

Comment: @Jeremy Actual number count? you mean like the total number of votes on a user? or number of votes value on a user "like 5 out of 10 and 9 out of 10 becomes 14" but either way all you need is an aggregator

Comment: Like total number of votes on a user

Comment: @jeremy you can do what with a view and place it in a block on a user profile, you will need a contextual filter to know which user are you looking at, and aggregate the number of votes on a user. i'll export you a view if you need it.

Comment: @saadlulu I am assuming you mean to use a view with some other module? (fivestar,vote,flag?) --  I would love an exported view to see how you have it setup if you don't mind.  That would be amazing!

Comment: found this, http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!fivestar!fivestar.module/function/fivestar_get_votes/7 give it a shot, if it still doesnt work we will find something else